# IJCADでC#で新規図面を開こうとすると「AutoCAD Mechanical Unknown形式図面です」。と警告が表示される

Tags: .net, ijcad

現在IJCAD2018を使用してC#で開発を行っております。
機能の1つに図面を作図して保存する機能があるのですが、
保存が完了した後に終了ボタンを押下して図面を閉じると
ドキュメントが0枚になることがあるので

```
DocumentCollection acDocMgr = Application.DocumentManager;
Document acDoc = acDocMgr.Add();
```

として新規図面を開く処理があるのですが、
このAddメソッドで図面を開く時に
「この図面はAutoCAD Mechanical Unknown形式図面です。」という警告が表示されています。
この警告を表示させないようにする方法を教えて頂けないでしょうか。

**追記**

Addメソッドで開こうとしている図面はAutoCAD2013形式で保存されている図面です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CADが対応していないAutoCAD Mechanicalのバージョンの図面を、開こうとしている為警告が表示されていると思われます。
https://support.ijcad.jp/hc/ja/articles/360000174142

確認ですが使用しているIJCADはメカニカルでしょうか？
例えば、IJCA DMechanical 2018 で AutoCAD Mechanical 2018形式で保存された図面を、 Add メソッドで開こうとするとイメージのような警告が表示されます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

通常のIJCAD2018ではメカニカル形式の図面を開いても警告は表示されないと思います。
(メカニカル特有のオブジェクトはACAD PROXY ENTITYとして扱われます。)

AutoCAD2013形式で保存されている図面であれば警告が表示されないと思いますが、開こうとしている図面がどのようなものかを確認することができませんので、一度IJCADのサポートに問題の図面を送ってみては如何でしょうか？